# How can I make regex pattern with characters, numbers, white space, double quotes, ?, !, commas, hyphen, dots, @ and &

Tags: regex, react-hooks

How can I make regex pattern allowing following `characters, numbers, white space, double quotes, ?, !, commas, hyphen, dots, @ and &`

```
                  <textarea
                    id="comments"
                    type="textarea"
                    placeholder='comments'
                    {...register("comments", {
                        required: true,
                        minLength: {
                            value: 5,
                            message: "Minimum length of 5 letters"
                        },
                        pattern: {
                            value: /^[a-z0-9]+$/i,
                            message: "Supports characters, numbers, white space, "", ?, !, @, & and commas"
                        }
                    })}
                    >
                  </textarea>
```

Comment: Just add all the additional characters to the `[]` character set in the regexp. You'll need to escape `-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
value: /^[a-z0-9]+$/i,
```

to

```
value: /^[a-z0-9\s"?!,\-.@&]+$/i,
```

`\s` is whitespace, and `-` needs to be escaped so it's not treated as the range separator. The rest is just the other characters you said you want to allow.